# SELECT COUNT (*) returning -1

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I need help with this one, when I run my query and put it in a variable it returns -1, anyone knows why?

```
OleDbCommand numberOfHomes = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM HOME", con);

int homes = numberOfHomes.ExecuteNonQuery();

lblNumberOfHomes.Text = homes.ToString();
```

This is done in Visual Studio 2013

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> anyone knows why?

Because you use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) for a query. You want to use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
int homes = (int)numberOfHomes.ExecuteScalar();
```

From the [ExecuteNonQuery-documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx):

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. **For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1**.

Comment: Thank you Tim, I changed it and now its giving me a cast error

System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Comment: @Ray: if you execute `numberOfHomes.ExecuteScalar()` in the debugger, what does it return? What database are you using at all?

Comment: I figured it out Tim, this is what I've done

    object homesNmbr = numberOfHomes.ExecuteScalar();
    int homes = Convert.ToInt32(homesNmbr);
    lblNumberofHomes.Text = homes.ToString();

That returned the correct number

Comment: @Ray: maybe `SELECT COUNT(*)` returns `long`, that's why `Convert.ToInt32` works but the direct cast not. It would have been interesting to know what type is returned from `numberOfHomes.ExecuteScalar()` in your database(?).